# Linux socket connect failed in Android

Tags: android, linux, sockets

I want to create a socket in Android with NDK, but sometimes I get some errors when connecting to server, and I can make sure that the network of the users' cell phone is available. 
One case is timeout error, and the other seems like connect refused, because I get the following logs, I think the second error is connect refused because the error from `getsockopt` is 111 even though the `strerror` give me Operation now in progress, but the server address is valid:

```
connect::socket error: Operation now in progress 
Or 
connect::error:111, Operation now in progress
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
bool connect(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len, int timeout) {
    int ret = 0;
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set mask;

    // set socket non block
    int flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    // use select to check socket connection
    ret = connect(sockfd, address, address_len);
    if (-1 == ret) {
        if (errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            perror("connect");
            inetConnectFailCode = errno;
            LOG(TAG.c_str(), "connect::errno != EINPROGRESS: %s", strerror(errno));
            return false;
        }
        LOG(TAG.c_str(), "connecting...\n");

        FD_ZERO(&mask);
        FD_SET(sockfd, &mask);
        tv.tv_sec = timeout;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        if (select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &mask, NULL, &tv) > 0) {
            int error = 0;
            socklen_t tmpLen = sizeof(int);
            int retopt = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &tmpLen);
            if (retopt != -1) {
                if (0 == error) {
                    LOG(TAG.c_str(), "has connect");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    //I get error here
                    LOG(TAG.c_str(), "connect::error:%d, %s", error, strerror(errno));
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                LOG(TAG.c_str(), "connect::socket error：%d", error);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            //timeout, and I get error here sometimes
            LOG(TAG.c_str(), "connect::socket error: %s", strerror(errno));
            return false;
        }
    }
    LOG(TAG.c_str(), "has connect");
    return true;
}
```

This problem has been bothering me for a long time, anybody can give me a favor, thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are displaying the wrong error message.

If `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)` fails, you are outputting `error` even though it does not have a valid value.  But, more importantly, if `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)` is successful, but `error` is not 0, you are passing `errno` to `strerror()` instead of passing `error`.  `errno` is still `EINPROGRESS` from the initial failed `connect()` call, so your error message says `"Operation now in progress"`. Error 111 is `ECONNREFUSED`, which would be `"Connection refused"` instead.

Also, if `select()` returns <= 0, you are outputting `strerror(errno)` regardless of what `select()` actually returned.  `errno` is only valid in that case if `select()` returns -1.  If `select()` returns 0 instead, it is not guaranteed to update `errno`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
bool connect(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len, int timeout) {
    // set socket non block
    int flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    // use select to check socket connection
    int ret = connect(sockfd, address, address_len);
    if (-1 == ret) {
        int error = errno;
        if (EINPROGRESS == error) {
            LOG(TAG.c_str(), "connecting...\n");

            fd_set mask;
            struct timeval tv;

            FD_ZERO(&mask);
            FD_SET(sockfd, &mask);

            tv.tv_sec = timeout;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            ret = select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &mask, NULL, &tv);
            if (0 < ret) {
                socklen_t tmpLen = sizeof(int);
                ret = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &tmpLen);
                if (-1 == ret) {
                    error = errno;
                }
            } else if (0 == ret) {
                error = ETIMEDOUT;
            } else {
                error = errno;
            }
        }

        if (0 != error) {
            inetConnectFailCode = error;
            LOG(TAG.c_str(), "connect::error:%d, %s", error, strerror(error));
            return false;
        }
    }

    LOG(TAG.c_str(), "has connect");
    return true;
}
```

With that said, you can get an `ECONNREFUSED` error if the server machine is reachable and receives your connection request, but actively refuses it because it cannot accept your connection at that time, either because:

- the requested port is not opened for listening.
- the listening socket's backlog of pending connections is full.

There is no way to differentiate which is the case, so you will just have to re-attempt the connection at a later time, preferably after an small interval of time elapses (say, at least 5 seconds, for instance).  Fail the connection if several attempts in succession all fail.

You can get an `ETIMEDOUT` error instead if the server machine is reachable and listening, but does not complete the 3-way handshake before your timeout period elapses.

Either error may also happen if a firewall blocks your connection.

**Update:** according to a comment on [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10308338/65863) I posted, only Windows servers cause `ECONNREFUSED` if the backlog is full. *Nix servers cause `ETIMEDOUT` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason you post may not happen, because the server to connect is a IM server, it works continuously, and we don't find any exceptional case. Other network requests (not to the IM server) of this App are normal that make it more confusing.

Comment: @wqycsu You are getting an `ETIMEDOUT` (110) or `ECONNREFUSED` (111) error. There are only a few ways those errors can happen during `connect()`, regardless of the *type* of server you are connecting to. Either 1) you are connecting to the wrong IP/Port, or it is not listening for connections, 2) the server is too busy to accept the connection at that moment, or 3) the connection is being blocked by a firewall/router.